List all WinRM listeners with property support
winrm e winrm/config/listener

Will list all listener, but displayed in string format. Like this :
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = B
    ListeningOn = 1.100.25.2, 127.0.0.1, 169.254.67.216, 169.254.74.33, 169.254.130.15, 172.20.0.1, 172.22.240.1, ::1

I can t isolate only Address field for example. Like $a.address.
Get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/listener

Needs selector Address and Transport to list listener.
Is it possible to tell  Get-WSManInstance to list all listener so i will be able to manipulate properties or will i have to split text output from winrm command?
Thanks.

You can pass a wildcard (*) for the address, and specify Transport using SelectorSet parameter.
Get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/listener -SelectorSet @{Address="*";Transport="http"}

(You can probably use Transport="*" as well, but i cant test it atm - worse case run the command twice with "http" and "https")

I tried but it will return the listener with Address="*" and not the listener with Address="IP:10.1.3.4" for exemple.

For the community :
# lister les connections et les effacer
# winrm e winrm/config/listener

$TABaddress = winrm e winrm/config/listener  | Select-String -allmatch Address | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split "=")[1].trim() }
$TABTransport = winrm e winrm/config/listener  | Select-String -allmatch Transport | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split "=")[1].trim() }

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $TABaddress.Length; $i++) {
    winrm delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=$($TABaddress[$i])+Transport=$($TABTransport[$i])
}

